# How to create Azure Cloud Service package from MsBuild in azure pipeline

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have some cloud service projects , which i am trying to get it into CI/CD. When i right click on the project from `Visual Studio` and click `Package` it  does what i want. I can see the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` and `ServiceDefinition.csdef` in the `bin\Release` folder after the package command is completed.

How can i achieve the same from an MSBuild command line ? I have tried

```
msbuild.exe 
/p:DeployTarget=Package 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:AutomatedBuild=True 
/p:configuration=release 
/p:outdir="D:\Pub" 
/p:targetprofile="Cloud" 
/target:Publish  
/p:SolutionDir=$/src/mysln/ WorkerRole.ccproj
```

What i get is the command completes and i can see around 241 dll and the required files in the folder. Am i missing something in the command argument ? Please advice

Edit : Also refered the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-publishing-a-cloud-service?view=vs-2019#publish-or-package-an-azure-application-from-visual-studio) , could'nt find anything

Edit 2 : Looks like  i can get the packages generated. Now the problem is doing this in VSTS. The build is failing with `" projectfile="*Undefined*Obfuscator\Maps\`

**Basically the solution path is becoming as undefined**

Edit 3 : Here's the error message when i try to build only the `CloudServiceProj`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5165,5): Error MSB3073: The command "if "Release" == "Debug" goto :exit
"*Undefined*Obfuscator\Tool\CO" projectfile="*Undefined*Obfuscator\Maps
```

The undefined is working fine locally , since it has the $(SolutionDir) variable in VS. Not sure how do i handle it here

**Update**

Here's the msbuild that am using

[image]

**Update 4**

I tried building the solution directly as suggested, but it has some .NET CORE as well as .NET Framework projects and i am getting this error

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.targets(163,11): Error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "Publish"..
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What i get is the command completes and i can see around 241 dll and the required files in the folder. Am i missing something in the command argument ?

For this question, you can try to change the argument `/p:outdir="D:\Pub"` to `/p:PublishDir="D:\Pub"`. That because the argument `outdir` is used to stored the output files not the publish files, it contains the build output of the projects (including the reference project). That the reason why there are around 241 dll and the required files in the folder.

As I test, if I change the argument to `PublishDir`, it works fine:

[image]

For the second question, I am not familiar with Azure Cloud Service, as I know about MSBuild/Visual Studio, we should build the "main" project instead of the reference project, so you can try to build the `AzureCloudService.ccproj` or build the solution file `.sln`.

Besides, when we build the project/solution, we do not need specify the solution folder, just specify the project file or solution directly:

```
msbuild.exe "TheRelativePathForYourSolutionInRepos.sln" /t:Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AutomatedBuild=True /p:configuration=release /p:TargetProfile=Cloud /p:PublishDir="D:\Pub"
```

If above not resolve your questions, please share your build error log in your question.

**Update:**

> For the second part, I have a post build event which does some
>   obfuscation .

If you have use any Macros, like `$(SolutionDir)` in your build event, but build the project file, you will got that error. Because the project reference information exists in the solution information, we can't access it when we only build one project.

Try to replace all `$(SolutionDir)` with `$(ProjectDir)..\`

**Update2:**

Since you can build the `.sln` file on your local without any issue, you could also build the `.sln` file with Azure pipeline. As test, I could build the .sln file in the Azure pipeline:

[image]

[image]

Besides, if you have replace `$(SolutionDir)` with `$(ProjectDir)..\`, how do you still get the error *Undefined*? Try to double check you build event, or you can share it in the question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo, the first part i have discovered it yesterday. Still thanks though. For the second part, I have a post build event which does some obfuscation . So after the build , the solution path gets undefined while directly building the `CloudServiceProject` as well

Comment: Added more log info in the question

Comment: @HariHaran, I have updated the answer, check if it helps you.

Comment: i still get undefined error even after changing $(SolutionDir) to `$(ProjectDir)..`

Comment: @HariHaran, share your MSBuild command line here, and have to change the `WorkerRole.ccproj` to the solution file in the command line?

Comment: I have updated the question again with the msbuild image

Comment: @HariHaran, Thanks for your quickly reply. Please try to select the .sln file in the Solution option in your build task, since I could not make sure you have use the correct path in the build event. If change to .sln not help, share your build event command line.

Comment: if i select the solution file in the `solution` option how do i point it to the `CloudService` project ? when i try /t:$src/ProjectFolder/.ccproj it does not work

Comment: @HariHaran, Sorry, not understand you correct, can you build the solution directly on your local with Visual Studio?

Comment: yes i can build the solution locally and am able to generate package as well in local , but only with `/p:SolutionDir =D:\src\rootFolderofSln` , i am not sure how can i specify this in the azurepipeline

Comment: I still cannot do this in azure pipelines, the same error is shown

Comment: @HariHaran, I have created a sample to test, it works fine on my side, you can check the update2 in my answer for details. And if it still not help, please share your build event in your question.

Comment: thanks again , one question is i have multiple projects under the same solution, in that case would the building direct solution with args work ?

Comment: @HariHaran, if you have multiple CloudServiceProject projects, it will give all projects the same args. In this case, if you need to set the different args to different projects, you need to build the project file, we have to resolve that issue in the build event.